# How to find out the mySQL query which uses most of the CPU using performance_sc

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat, cpu-usage, performance-tuning

[52893 TID is using 100% CPU in my server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmpej.png)

How to find the query corresponds to that TID? For me, [this table is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JSfx.png)

Comment: Use the slowlog instead:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog  The slowlog won't give you CPU, but it will give you the worst queries, which are likely to be high-CPU.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks. But the URL is inaccessible for me. Could you please share the queries directly instead?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL and MariaDB optionally create a "slowlog" file or table.

Setup:

```
⚈  Set long_query_time = 1 -- Preferrable in my.cnf We may change that threshold up or down later, but this is a reasonable start.
⚈  Set up the slowlog to be captured to FILE.
⚈  Turn on (the details of this vary with the Version)
⚈  Wait at least 24 hours.
```

Writing slow_log to file -- this is preferred, since there are tools for condensing such:

```
   log_output = FILE
   slow_query_log = ON
   slow_query_log_file = (fullpath to some file)
   long_query_time = 1
   log_slow_admin_statements = ON
   log_queries_not_using_indexes = OFF
```

Notes:

```
⚈  log_output can be TABLE to write to mysql.slow_log, or FILE,TABLE to write both
⚈  slow_query_log_file has a default; is not needed for TABLE
⚈  long_query_time is a float, and can be as low as 0, but that gets verbose; default is a 'useless' 10
⚈  admin statements tend to be slow but infrequent
⚈  not_using_indexes is mostly clutter; simply worry about those that are slow
⚈  If running on a Slave, consider using log_slow_slave_statements
⚈  Beginning with 8.0.14, also have log_slow_extra = ON
```

Other options (version dependent; incomplete):

```
   log_slow_rate_limit=100
   log_slow_rate_type=query
   log_slow_verbosity=full
   slow_query_log_always_write_time=1
   slow_query_log_use_global_control=all
   innodb_monitor_enable=all
   userstat=1
```

Gather results for me (preferrably using FILE):

```
⚈  Digest the results using either of these:

`pt-query-digest`  -- from Percona.com
`mysqldumpslow -s t`

⚈  Grab the first few (perhaps 5) queries. They will be sorted by (frequency * avg-time), which is the most useful.
⚈  Provide SHOW CREATE TABLE -- for each table
⚈  Provide EXPLAIN SELECT ... -- for each query
```

Analyze Results: Usually (not always), I can then provide a concrete suggestion on speeding up each query:

```
⚈  Add a particular index (often 'composite')
⚈  Reformulate the query (a simple case is not hiding an indexed column in a function; more complex involves adding/removing subqueries)
⚈  Recommend schema change
⚈  Possibly even an architectural change (EAV is a common problem)
```

Comment: Occasional updates to the above are maintained in https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Answer (score 1):

SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; might be more useful if the process is still running.  The complete query would be listed.